# FileActionResult returns a corrupt file

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have download (pdf) file feature in our app and this was implemented months ago, if not longer. It always worked fine but I haven't used it in some time so I don't know when the problem started to occur.

When the user clicks on a button, it downloads a pdf file but I don't understand why the file nearly doubles in size when saved to the download folder and while it is displaying the correct number of pages, the pdf content is not visible, so clearly corrupted.

I've added some code to output the file to a folder just before it is downloaded, it has the correct size and is not corrupted.

I have this line in my controller

```
return new FileActionResult(document);
```

When the above line is executed, it executes a custom `IHttpActionResult` (called FileActionResult) with the following code:

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    var filename = this.Document.GetFilename();
    var mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filename);

    response.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(this.Document.ToData()));

    response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = this.Document.Data.Length;
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(mimeType);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new
      ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
      {
         FileName = filename,
      };

    return Task.FromResult(response);
}
```

The following are all being set correctly:

- Content (binary data with 80352 bytes)
- ContentLength is being set correctly (80532)
- ContentType (application/pdf)
- ContentDisposition (& Filename) (...Sheet.pdf)

[image]

So as you can see the file should be around 80Kb, but instead it is:

[image]

And when I open it, all I get is a blank page (or pages when a multi-page pdf).

I didn't include the JavaScript that triggers the call as it's clearly made and the file is being downloaded but it is somehow corrupted and I need to find out why.

I've tried it in MS Edge and Google Chrome, and the behaviour is the same.

Any ideas what could be causing this or is there a work-around?

**Update-1:**

This is the JavaScript that handles the data being returned from my web api:

```
let URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
let binaryData = [];
binaryData.push(blob);
let newBlob = new Blob(binaryData);
var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
if (filename) {
    // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    // safari doesn't support this yet
    if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
        window.location.href = downloadUrl;
    } else {
        a.href = downloadUrl;
        a.download = filename;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
    }
} else {
    window.location.href = downloadUrl;
}
```

Based on the current file I'm downloading,

The blob (source) variable size is: 477365 bytes

When pushed to the array called binaryData, it remains at 477365 bytes

but when the binaryData is passed to `new Blob(binaryData)` the newBlob variable size is now 860744 bytes.

Surely that can't be right?

[image]

This must be slightly compressed when transferred as the file itself when I check the size in the web api end, is 500362 bytes.

Also, I think, I may have spotted what the problem is but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Both of these snapshots are from the file I'm dealing with for my test.

The first is created in my web api before it is downloaded (only for test purpose)

[image]

The second is from the download file:

[image]

As you can see, from the few highlights, it's like the encoding is incorrect once it is created in the Blob object. I'm not sure tbh but will research it further unless someone lets me know before then on how to fix this.

Comment: What is the result of `yourMemoryStream.Length`? (Store the memorystream in an intermediate variable) You shouldn't need to set the `ContentLength` it will be set automatically from the stream length

Comment: Error seems to be at the server since Edge and Chrome also fails.  Edge, Chrome, and c# shared same user settings so it could be a setting that changed.  The file is larger which may indicate that GZIP isn't being used.  My best guess is a firewall was updated and may be blocking unsigned PDF files.  The firewall was changed to block untrusted PDF files.

Comment: @jdweng interesting suggestion as we recently changed our anti-virus/firewall provider, so it could be down to this alright. I'm going to update my answer as I found out more.

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for the suggestion. Will try that and revert back but I did find something else interesting and it maybe related to JavaScript but not 100% sure just yet.

Comment: Why are you intercepting the FileContentResult and rebuilding the response? Is there another reason for it? I've never had any troubles getting what I wanted using it.

Comment: Or are you. Where is the `ExecuteAsync` method?

Comment: @phuzi At the type, I just followed up an example on how to achieve file download that used a Web API and JavaScript to handle the response. I've updated my answer as I've figured out a work-around/different way to handle it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out a work-around after trying a lot of different things.

1. As I'm using Ajax, I added the following:

   xhrFields: {
   responseType: 'blob'
   },
2. I've simplified the blob handling to:

   const URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
   const downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(data);
3. and the full code looks like this

   ```
   $.ajax({
    url: downloadUrl,
    method: 'PUT',
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    xhrFields: {
        responseType: 'blob'
    },
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + gbl_Token
    }
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        ...
        } else {
            const URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            const downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(data);

            if (filename) {
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                    window.location.href = downloadUrl;
                } else {
                    a.href = downloadUrl;
                    a.download = filename;
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                }
            } else {
                window.location.href = downloadUrl;
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   ...

Unfortunately, I still don't understand why this feature broke after having worked for so long and I know that I wouldn't have modified that as I haven't had to look at either sections in the Web API and JavaScript, so something else has changed and can only assume that it has something to do with Chromium/JavaScript, more specifically, the Blob object. Could be wrong but as explained in my question, this is where things doubled in size and clearly got messed up.